# Adding specified numbers of zeros after the floating point to a decimal type

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

Is there any way I can add a specified number of zeros after the significant part of the number after the floating point to a decimal type without using string.Format() to avoid performance issues?

For example say I have the number:

```
var number = 5.023m;
```

And I want to add 5 zeros (this can vary) after the number so it becomes

```
number = 5.02300000;
```

Comment: Why would you add zeroes if *not* for the purpose of formatting? It won't change the numerical value.

Comment: We would like to save us from creating another property if possible.

Comment: I'm still not getting what you're after. My point is that whether the number is `5.02300000` or `5.023` is not going to be relevant to anything except a final step that formats the number as a string representation. At that point, since the value is getting formatted anyway, you may as well incorporate your precision logic, and indeed, it makes little sense and is very obscure to add it anywhere else, since you're hoping/expecting that the precision won't change at some other point, which is very brittle.

Comment: `number += 0.00000000m;` does it but i doubt that it helps you in the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the number to string, add it zeros and then convert it back to decimal, here is an example:

```
var number = 5.023m;
var numberAsString=number.ToString();
int n = 5; //add n zeros, e.g n=5
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    numberAsString += '0';
number = decimal.Parse(numberAsString);
Console.WriteLine(number);// output:  5.02300000
```

Comment: Now implement the "this can vary" requirement, which needs more than a compile-time constant. Spoilers: that's not fun at all.

Comment: The proposed revision technically avoids `string.Format`, but at the cost of something even more inefficient, so I doubt that's what the OP's after. A more efficient version of that idea (in terms of generating less garbage) is `decimal.Parse(number.ToString() + new string('0', n)")`, but if you're going to throw in string conversion at all, it makes the most sense to do that only once, and only at the end, and without converting back to `Decimal` and hoping the precision remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the [`String.PadRight()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padright?view=net-7.0)?

```
var number = 5.023m;
var s = number.ToString(".###");
string text = s.PadRight(s.Length+5,'0');
```

Comment: Interesting. I might try it, the only issue is that there's still conversion to string here but to avoid useless complications we might leave it like that.

Comment: @squezzi: When you are talking about zeros after significant figures, it is logical to talk about formatting for text representation. Otherwise, I don't understand the meaning of your question. if you mean **rounding**, then formulate the question more precisely. There are special functions for rounding.